# How to increase the specificity of a class of props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a component with a button. It has a default class and a class passed to its from the props. But sometimes the default class overwrites the class from the props. Is it possible to increase the specificity of the class from the props or lower the specificity of the default class?

1. Do not suggest using !important
2. Do not suggest to prescribe default styles for the button tag, I do not want to apply them to all buttons in the project
3. Assigning an id for each button is also not an option
4. In the props, it is the class name that needs to be passed, not the style

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './Button.module.scss'
import classNames from 'classnames'

const Button = ({ children, className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <button {...props} className={classNames(styles.btn, className)}>
      {children}
    </button>
  )
}
```

I can't find a beautiful and convenient solution. Now I'm adding !imortant in a class of props.
I just hope there's some css or js trick I'm not aware of.

Comment: What does your css look like? You can add specificity with parent elements, tags, etc. `parentTag.parentClass targetTag.targetClass {...}`

Comment: @user1599011 , I can do this, but then I'll have to add a wrapper for the component with the button every time. It's also inconvenient as writing !important in styles

Comment: Does the button not have one or more parents as it is? I wasn't suggesting adding parents, but buttons don't typically exist in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Any additional selector will be increase priority of passed classname

`component.module.scss`:

```
button.passed-class-name {
 color: red;
}
```

`button.module.scss`:

```
.btn {
  color: green
}
```

`Component.js`

```
import styles from './component.module.scss'
import { Button } from 'components/Button'

const Component = () => {
    <Button className={styles.passedClassName} />
}
```

Comment: This way I can increase the specificity of default styles, and I need to lower their specificity.
I won't be able to increase the specificity of the styles from the props this way.

Comment: You will. Styles from props will be more specific if you write them in the way I 
show.

Comment: Focus RS, the class comes to the component in the props, in js. How do I apply it in css as you suggested?

Comment: @Saithirius Where do you get className to pass it through props? I think there is another scss file

Comment: Do you suggest writing styles in parent components like this? Yes, this is an option, but also not convenient, almost like writing !important. This is an additional rule that you need to remember and follow every time you use the button. On the contrary, I would like to get rid of the rules, and use the component as a regular button and have my styles automatically overwrite the default ones in case of conflicts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244799/discussion-between-focus-rs-and-saithirius).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution could not be found. I decided not to reinvent the wheel and write a UI kit for the project, like everyone else.
UI kit styles are connected earlier, so styles from parents will rewrite them without !important and without increasing specificity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).